# How can I get the first matched element with a CSS selector that has different parents?

Tags: html, css

With the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <span class="something">...</span>
  <span class="something">...</span>
  <span class="something">...</span>
</div>
<article>
  <span class="something">...</span>
</article>
```

I want to find the first `.something`. How would I do this?

Comment: Did you tried this `div + .something {}` and `article + .something {}` ?

Comment: `div > span.something:first-child {}` might work.

Comment: @CalebDenio but what if first span won't have `.something` class

Comment: And what if the first `.something` is in a `<p>`

Comment: Then, just change it to `div > .something:first-child {}`

Comment: But that would only return divs with children "something".  I think he wants it to return any HTML elements that have .something children and select the first of each.

Comment: actually I have some idea

Comment: @Shamoon please elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve this with only CSS. However, JavaScript's `document.querySelector` can be used to obtain the first element on the page matching a selector.

```js
const first = document.querySelector('.something');
first.style.backgroundColor = "dodgerblue";
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="something">...</span>
  <span class="something">...</span>
  <span class="something">...</span>
</div>
<article>
  <span class="something">...</span>
</article>
```

In order to affect pseudo elements, you can add a class to the element found with `document.querySelector` and add another style declaration in your CSS.

```js
const first = document.querySelector('.something');
first.classList.add("first");
```

```css
.something.first:after {
  content: "I'm the first one!";
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="something">...</span>
  <span class="something">...</span>
  <span class="something">...</span>
</div>
<article>
  <span class="something">...</span>
</article>
```

Comment: I need an `::after`, can I do that?

Comment: If that's the case, then can I just do `.first::after`?

Comment: @Shamoon Yes, you can, unless you are going to be adding the class to other elements.

Comment: I'll try in a bit and let you know

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to achieve this purely with CSS. It would have been possible if all the elements with the `.something` class would have had the same parent (see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107)). But since they are spread over multiple parents this won't work.

You can use jQuery for this which has a `:first` selector:

```js
$( ".something:first" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

```css
div, article {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100px;
}

span { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="something">Something</span>
    <span class="something">Something</span>
    <span class="something">Something</span>
</div>
<article>
    <span class="something">Something</span>
</article>
```